# How Would I Turn Mysqli Table Results into a menu with drop down

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, mysqli

Here Is my question: What I am wanting To do is Take Results from a mysql table and turn them into a menu and a drop down menu

HERE IS A QUICK EXAMPLE:
if you see in my mysql table i have page_name and parent, So the example is:
page_name and if i have row 1 the page_name is 'Home' now it's parent is 'none' right but on id number 39 the page_name is 'Contact Us' and the Parent Is 'Far Far Away 123' so if the parent is equal to 'none' then it will show at the top of the menu not the drop down if it has a parent it will show under that parent like this:

```
Home | the ben page | The Brock Page | Far Far Away 123 | dsfk
                                       Contact Us
```

You see Contact Us is under Far Far Away Because the parent Is Far Far Away 123

here is my table:
[image: Mysql databse Image]

Here is my code That I am trying but it is not working for some reason:

```
<ul>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages ORDER by item_order";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
confirm_query($result);
while ($links = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
if($links['parent'] !== "none") {
?>
<li id = "<?php echo $links['id']; ?>"><a href="
<?php 
 echo "page.php?id=" . $links['id'] . "\" title=\"" . $links['page_title'] .     "\"";
?>>
<?php
  echo $links['page_name'];
?>
</a>

<?php
if($links['parent'] !== "none") {
$child = "";




$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($row['parent'] !== "none") {
        $child = $row['page_name'];     
}
}

echo "<ul id=\"sub_menu\" class=\"sub_navagation" . $links['id'] . "\">";
echo "<li>";
echo $child;
echo "<li>";
echo "</ul>";
}
?>

</li>
<?php   
}
}
?>

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#sub_menu {
    display: none;
}

#sub_menu:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Ok if as you can see i have the parent row in the MYSQL table and on id number 39 i want the 'Far Far Away123' to be the parent of Contact Us and i want to show it when i hover over 'Far Far Away123'

Comment: So what's the problem? Is the HTML output what you expect? Are you getting correct results from your database, if not what results are you not getting and what are you expecting for those results?

Comment: Check this link http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/website-design/using-css/simple-css-drop-down-menu#html-code you will get a sample css html dropdown menu. And as a suggestion it will be better to store parent menu id in your table instead of name.

Comment: You need to build a tree structured array or object before render menu links, so you can get right child nodes. Here is similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007826/creating-an-array-using-recursive-php-from-mysql

Comment: i don't care about the css i can do that my self just getting the results is my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to build out an array of all the results.  Then run through that array (instead of multiple database queries).

I added a function `build_dropdown()` that will take the page name and run through the array of pages to see if there are any items with a parent matching.  If so, we make an array of those items and run through them to build the dropdown menu.  If not, it does nothing and moves on to the next menu item.

```
<?php

  function build_dropdown ($parent, $pages){
    foreach($pages as $page){
      if($page['parent'] == $parent){
        $items = $page;
      } // END if
    } // END foreach

    if(is_array($items)){ // If a sub 
      echo '<ul id="sub_menu" class="sub_navagation'. $item['id'] .'">';
      foreach($items as $item){
        echo '<li>'.$item['name'].'<li>';
      } // END foreach
      echo '</ul>'; 
    } // END if 
  }

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages ORDER by item_order";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  confirm_query($result);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $pages[] = $row; // Add each row to $pages array to use later
  }

  foreach($pages as $key => $page){

    if($page['parent'] == 'none'){ ?>

      <li id = "<?php echo $page['id']; ?>">
        <a href="page.php?id=<?php echo $page['id']; ?>" title="<?php echo $page['page_title']; ?>">
          <?php echo $page['page_name']; ?>
        </a>
        <?php
          build_dropdown($page['page_name'], $pages); // If there are child items then build them out
        ?>
      </li> 

<?php 
    } // END if

  } // END foreach
?>
```

Comment: will i need to change anything sir?

Comment: I don't believe so.  I tried to match up with your database columns

Comment: when i echo out my result it is just duplicating the child elements like this: 

Parent
   Child
   Child
   Child
   Child

Comment: when i only have one child element and all my pages are named diffrently

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you will need to JOIN your table to basically query it again to get the parent value, and add that to your markup.

```
SELECT *
FROM Pages
LEFT JOIN Pages p2 on page_name = p2.parent
```

(note: the syntax above may not be right, but I wanted to give you an idea of where I would start).